# How to get old options back in Nautilus's "Connect to server" window?

Tags: 12.10, server, nautilus

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 with GNOME 3.6 Classic. When I try to use *Places* -> *Connect to server*, I get a window missing all the options I was used to in Ubuntu 11.10 (such as *SSH*).

I can only insert the IP address of the remote machine. It is the same as if I use a normal Nautilus browser window and enter the address there. Where can I configure the system to have full options?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 13.04 but I think it's similar to 12.10 in this regard.

You will need to specify the connection metho in the box that appears:

1. for secure ftp/ssh: `sftp://user@serverip`
2. for samba (windows network share): `smb://user@serverip`
3. etc.

[image]

*NB it will save your connection settings in the "Recent Servers" section so you don't have to re-enter them each time*